# How preserve edit permissions for the copy of a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, edit, user-permissions

I have a problem similar to one posted on the [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/el9NscDC5_A;context-place=topicsearchin/drive/allow$20editing$20a$20copy$20of$20a$20spreadsheet$20without).

The answer given there described a way which requires action from the recipients of the link to make a copy of the Google Spreadsheet by themselves.

There is a script, which creates a personal folder for a person who wants to edit the COPY of the Google Spreadsheet. Than the the ORIGINAL Google Spreadsheet copied into a newly created folder:

```
fileforanswers.makeCopy(fileforanswers.getName(), targetFolder);
```

The permissions for the COPY set:

```
fileforanswers.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT)"
```

The Google Spreadsheet contains 1 sheet.
The protection settings for the COPY of the Google Spreadsheet "SHEET" are:

```
if (protection && protection.canEdit()) { protection.remove(); }
```

For the "RANGE" are:

```
if (protection && protection.canEdit()) { protection.remove(); }
```

The link contains the ID of the COPY of the Google Spreadsheet.
When the COPY of the Google Spreadsheet accessed by its own link directly by a person who wants to fill it Google Sheets allows to VIEW it only

The settings described above are set manually for the ORIGINAL Google Spreadsheet. When the ORIGINAL Google Spreadsheet accessed by its own link by the same person the same way described in case of the COPY, Google Sheets allows to EDIT the ORIGINAL.

What else required to allow in the script to enable editing of the COPY of the Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

The `.makeCopy` method returns the copy file. your second code line appears to explain what you are describing in that you are setting the sharing on thefile you have copied and not the copy.

Try setting the permissions on the returned File object:

```
var copyOfOriginal = fileforanswers.makeCopy(fileforanswers.getName(), targetFolder);

copyOfOriginal.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT)"
```

Comment: thanks for help. There is a change, but no solution yet. Screenshots - COPY before (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6aDIsqDzW58ajh6VEM5YjlCYlU); COPY after (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6aDIsqDzW58N05RV1pOZGJxNXc)  Unchanged - the ORIGINAL editable on any computer/any OS (MSW7/Linux(Ubntu) with no restrictions.

Comment: is the original editable before touched by any script at all?

Comment: Yes, it is. The original created manually, permissions, protections also set manually. It is editable with no restrictions.

Comment: It looks, the problem of editing permissions solved already.
The final step is to send a link of the personal copy of a spreadsheet to the respondents.
The only way notify respondents about the link of their personal copy of a spreadsheet exclusively in a HTML message, because they keep their emails hidden.
The solution has to be a message appearing in the respondent's browser window after the form closes with the confirmation message.

Comment: I found solutions for sending notifications from the spreadsheet of answers in email, but there isn't any idea how to display a message in the respondents browser window where the form was closed.
Could you show a hint how to display a message in respondent's browser window containing the link?

Comment: Best you ask that as a separate question